# Total Commander synchronize directories shows identical files as different

Tags: total-commander

not sure why but when I click on synchronize directories, it shows identical files as different.

[image]

How do I get these files to not show as different?

Comment: Well, the files are different sizes so they are not identical. were they created or edited on different operating systems?

Comment: They are identical by content, and I selected the checkbox "by Content". What else can I do so that TC ignores file size? I dont see such option.

Comment: If they have different line ending characters they are not identical by content. You would not see the difference but a file comparison at the byte level would. I suspect that this is the cause of the issue that you are seeing. Here is an article discussing using Total Commander and comparing files while ignoring line endings. http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=264342 Essentially you need to tell TC to use an external file comparison tool and configure that tool to ignore line endings.

Comment: I understand, but as a regular user, I shouldn't bother with all these details, so I understood it is not possible to compare these files properly using TC? only external folder comparison application?

Comment: I don't use Total Commander so all I can tell you is what is in that link. The creators of Total Commander understood that there are many different way to compare files so they incorporated the ability to use an external program for the comparison.

Comment: The "binary" check box visible in the above screenshot would probably be enough to show you the difference. Note "unix style" line endings are 1 byte (for... line feed?) and the windows style is 2-byte (carriage return & line feed), the file depicted is 8 bytes larger, and there are 8 line endings

Comment: Again, the poster ***does not*** want the files to report as different. He (or she) wants Total Commander to see them as the same.

Comment: There, now it does.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it has more something to do with the 'line termination' of different platforms.

The file on the left (156 bytes) should have CRLF endings (2 bytes for every 'new line' character) (Windows/DOS platform).

The file on the right (148 bytes) should have LF endings (1 byte for every 'new line' character) (Linux/UNIX platform).

Because of the 9 lines (and 8 EOLs [End of Line]), this makes a difference of 8 bytes while the other contents in those files remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Install BeyondCompare (e.g. version 4).
After install for Compare set
 - Arguments: `%1 %2 /title1=%6 /title2=%7`
 - Extension: `.*`

Afterwards you can use it from Total Commander context menu like screenshot shows:

[image: Select Left File For Compare]
[image: Compare to \"selected left file]

Comment: Beyond Compare costs money

Answer (score -3):

in IT domain knowledge, people compare **hash values** to decide identical files.

There are few hash methods, the common ones are **MD5 and SH1**. You can google with keywords: MD5 checksum and / or SH1 checksum

Back to total commander, this website gives you hint how to use total commander add-ons which giving you MD5 / SH1 hash comparison.

http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=14567&view=next

that is, back to your question, the answer is: **do not use compare content**. Use hash methods to compare files.

Comment: Well, in this case the MD5 and the SH1 (and any other hashing algorithm that I know of) would show the files as different which is *not* what the OP wants.

Comment: You are missing the point. Using a hash would show the two files as different. The poster wants Total Commander to see the files as the ***same*** not different.

Comment: EBGreen, exactly! As on the screenshot I provided, two files are identical by visible content (file size is different, no idea why and dont care), I see the content is the same and I want TC to show these files as identical, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, according to the link I provided it is possible. You just need to tell Total Commander to use a comparison tool that can ignore line endings.

Comment: @monstro... you need to be careful, the difference may not be at the end of file. It is possible to have **non-printable-characters in the middle** between for..loop for example... therefore as i wrote above, you need to change how you comparing files

Comment: One more time...Ignoring line ending characters (which is a very common issue in mixed OS development environments) would show the files as the same but would still show them as different if there were unprintable character differences. In this use case, hash comparison is still wrong. Byte comparison ignoring line endings does what the OP want s and still catches the edge case that you have brought up.

Comment: can you proof there is no non-printable characters in the screen ? cannot right ? people press enter between programming lines and it does happens sometimes

Comment: @EBgreen, you cannot give answers without holistic views, only assumption that it's is only end of files, without througly checking about non-printable-characters

Comment: You keep saying end of file. I keep saying end of line. Which do you mean? Because I mean end of line. This is a very common issue. Having an extra end of line would show as a difference when ignoring end of line characters. *nix and windows by default use different characters to indicate an end of a line. When a comparison utility is told to ignore end of line characters, it does not ignore that an end of line happens. It simply considers the end of line characters to match whether they are *nix style or windows style.

Comment: And no I cannot prove that there are not non-printable characters in the file but that is what a comparison utility is for.

Comment: guys, when I use Beyond Compare, I have no such problem, all these files are shown as identical by content as they are text files. I may not know anything about encodings and line endings or non-printable chars or anything else...

Comment: So in Total Commander tell it to use Beyond Compare for the comparison. The files demonstrably are not the same but it sounds like Beyond Compare is set to ignore line endings. Use it.

Comment: @monstro, it's good you say you don't know. I am telling you so you know. Would you mind mark the question as answered ? i am collectiong points. thanks

Comment: Your answer literally gives the opposite result of what he is asking for...

Comment: @Hongkie, I didnt say I dont know :) please read carefully | EBGreen, I dont have Beyound Compare at work :) thats why I am asking... if I can use TC the same way

Comment: Well, in that case then I would guess the answer is no. Total Commander by itself will not do what you want. I do not use TC myself, I am basing that on the link I provided on the TC forum where they discussed exactly this issue.

Comment: @EBgreen, my answers undertones like you wrote above: Total commander by itself will not do what you want.